# Likeliness of getting University posts outside India when you started doing PhD at 35 in Mathematics

Tags: mathematics, career-path, teaching, university

I need to tell you somewhat about myself first so that you people can better understand my situation. I did intermediate in 2005, then I did nothing until 2018 (bipolar disorder), but I recovered and started a BSc in 2019.

I did my "distance learning" BSc from IGNOU (very reputed in India for distance learning). I passed my BSc in 2022, and I got selected for MSc cum PhD programme in elite "Indian Institute of Science, Bangalore, India in 2022.

Now, my age is 35 at time of entering in the Institute.
My professors say you wouldn't be able to hold any academic position in India even after your PhD.

So I want to ask you all is there some hope outside India as carrier opportunities in Mathematics? I am very worried even after getting selected in the research institute. Please help me if you think you can by suggesting or guiding me for my carrier.

Comment: Getting an academic job in mathematics in the US/UK/EU is very difficult regardless of age.

Comment: I hope you take this helpfully, but I just tidied up your post, and your English is far from being ready to teach in an English-speaking country. It would be helpful to tag what countries you'd be interested in moving to.

Answer (score 1):

The binding factor won't be your age or where you studied. If you have done good work in your doctorate then you are competitive.

However, in many places, the academic market isn't very good at the present time and many people are having trouble getting a permanent position. Many do post-docs and hope to move to a permanent position. There is a lot of competition.

But, you won't know for sure until you make some applications. Make a broad search, not only in top institutions. For the US, note that there are many (many) teaching institutions that need good mathematics instruction, but require little research. Also note that in the US, letters of recordation are very important compared to other places.

In any application stress your accomplishments and your likelihood of future success, not the things that held you back initially. Try to make the same true in any letters of recommendation.

Note also that much of the competition will be from people who studied in the country they are applying for. That can make it hard for any international student unless a place is actively looking to diversify faculty.

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, someone who has never studied nor taught in the US has zero chance of getting a teaching-oriented permanent position (in the US) and very little chance of getting a teaching-oriented temporary position.